# Adicionando items a uma lista e adicionando evento de click em seguida - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou estudando [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) e desenvolvendo uma *Todo List*.

A única coisa que eu quero fazer é adicionar elementos à uma `<ul>` e logo em seguida habilitá-los para `click` para que apenas mudem de classe.

Meu `html` que é muito simples...Esse `js` já está uma zona porque já tentei de tudo e nada funciona...

```js
var addBtn = document.querySelector("button");
var inputText = document.getElementsByTagName("input").value;
var inputT = document.getElementById("addLista");
var listaCompleta = document.querySelector("#listaCompleta");
var itensLista = document.getElementsByClassName("notDone");

function updateLista (lista){
    return lista
}
var listaOk = updateLista(itensLista)

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var liAdd = document.getElementById("addLista").value;    
    if (liAdd !== "") {
        var liNova = document.createElement("li");
        liNova.textContent = liAdd;
        liNova.classList.add("notDone");
        listaCompleta.appendChild(liNova);
        liLength = itensLista.length
        console.log(liLength);     
        itensLista = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    }
    inputT.value = "";
    listaOk = updateLista(itensLista)
});

function click (listaOk){
for( var i = 0; i <= listaOk.length; i++){   
    if(listaOk[i]){
        listaOk[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       this.classList.toggle("done");
            })
    }
}
}

click(listaOk);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type ="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="todoStyle.css">
    <title>Todo Dom</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <div class="central">
       <form action="">
           Adicione um Item: <input type="text" id="addLista" name="addLista"> <button type="button">add</button></form>   
        <ul id="listaCompleta">
        
        
        </ul>
    </div>



    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todoJs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exemplo que você tem, eu adicionei as classes (que muda as cores do item de vermelho para azul) e uma função chamada `atualizarEvento`, que adiciona o evento de clique para o último item adicionado na lista, que é invocada após a adição do elemento:

```js
var addBtn = document.querySelector("button");
var inputT = document.getElementById("addLista");
var listaCompleta = document.querySelector("#listaCompleta");
var itensLista = document.getElementsByClassName("notDone");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var liAdd = document.getElementById("addLista").value;
  if (liAdd !== "") {
    var liNova = document.createElement("li");
    liNova.textContent = liAdd;
    liNova.classList.add("notDone");
    listaCompleta.appendChild(liNova);
    liLength = itensLista.length
    itensLista = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  }
  inputT.value = "";
  atualizarEvento();
});

function atualizarEvento() {
  var lis = document.getElementById("listaCompleta").getElementsByTagName("li");

  lis[lis.length - 1].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
  })

}
```

```css
.done {
  color: red !important;
}
.notDone {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Todo List</h1>
<div class="central">
  <form action="">
    Adicione um Item:
    <input type="text" id="addLista" name="addLista">
    <button type="button">add</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="listaCompleta">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, amigo. Realmente deu certo.
Só gostaria de saber o que havia de errado com a minha lógica usando o "for".

Comment: Na verdade eu não entendi muito bem a forma que você estava tentando fazer, e usando `for` irá repetir o `addEventListener` a cada adição de item (o que pode causar alguns erros) - por isso deixei dessa forma, de adicionar o ouvinte ao último item adicionado.

Comment: @BrunoT, se a resposta lhe atendeu podes marcar como aceita :)